# ERROR: Failed to get instance configuration from IAP Workbench

Tags: endeca, endeca-workbench

When I try to run the baseline update on endeca, it failed and show this message on terminal:

> [01.09.18 17:07:58] INFO: Error in Baseline update.Utility 'emgr_update_get_ws_settings' failed. Refer to utility logs in [ENDECA_CONF]/logs/shell on host ITLHost.

There is this message on the log file pointed out:

> ERROR: Failed to get instance configuration from IAP Workbench.

But i dont know where fix it. ( I'm learning Endeca)

Does someone know what to do next?

Comment: Can you please provide information about version of platform, if you use the oob Discover application or a custom application etc.

Comment: Also is workbench  up and running at port 8006(or the port you set during installation) and accessible?

Comment: It`s a custom application. MDEX 6.4.1.2; Platform Service 6.1.4; Workbench 2.1.2. Yeh, the workbench is running and accessible=)

Comment: Can you see the application in Workbench? Is it initialized properly?

Comment: This error is mainly due to your workbench being down. Kindly restart your IAP workbench and check again.